# PHP update query, code revision

Tags: php, sql-update

I have two functions on the same webpage, each of them will update one different table on the same database depending which button you press.

This function modifies one table and works:

```
function SaveMItem()
    {
    $DayOfWeekNumber = 0;
        if ($_POST['selDayOfTheWeek'])
        {$DayOfWeekNumber = $_POST['selDayOfTheWeek'];}

        mysql_query("UPDATE tblMItem SET ItemText = '" . $_POST['txtFirstOne'] . "' WHERE MenuItemID = " . (1 + $DayOfWeekNumber));
            echo "SaveMItem Ok";
    }

function SavetblAnnouncement(){

    mysql_query("UPDATE TblAnuncios SET Title=".$_POST['txtAnnouncementTitle']. ",Content=".$_POST['txtAnnouncementContent']." WHERE 1");

    echo "Completed announcement" ;  
    }
```

When I press SaveMItem button I can see the message SaveMItem Ok and it saves new values on Table.

When I press SavetblAnnouncement button I can see the message Completed announcement but the table TblAnuncios will not get updated.

As this is on the same file, the Database is the same and the function SaveMItem is able to update the table I suppose the connexion to the DB is ok.

Can anyone let me know what am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: your update query should update whole table's all record with the same.

Comment: Before analyzing what is really going on: use error handling! You blindly trust that things work and now you _guess_ what might be wrong. MySQL certainly throws an error, tells you what is wrong, but you don't listen! Check the manual for phps mysql extension and read how to detect errors.

Comment: Apart from that: the mysql extension is depreciated, use mysqli or PDO instead and your code is currently wide open to sql injections!

Comment: Suggestion, [**Don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: Your echo will display as it's no where connected with the query. Use error handlers to get the error in your query and show the message if error handler does not show any errors

Comment: your update query will update the whole table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing quotes around the values.

```
    $title = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['txtAnnouncementTitle']);
    $txt = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['txtAnnouncementContent']);
    mysql_query("UPDATE TblAnuncios SET Title='".$title. "',Content='".$txt."' WHERE 1");
```

You should also escape the string, both to prevent SQL injection and also to make the query correct if the title or text contains quote characters.